# Indicate a cron is running on OSX (popup?)

Tags: macos, popup, cron

I have a cron that runs a build script on a mac. I would like a way to create a popup or launch a terminal window while this cron is running to indicate that the process is running.

What's the easiest way to do this? An applescript thing to launch a popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `growlnotify`, the command line interface to [Growl](http://growl.info/extras.php).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Just skimming the API, I didn't find a way to make a notification stay up until the cron is done running. How would I do this?

Comment: There's more information on the `man` page that gets installed.  You may have to adapt a bit to the way Growl does things but it is the defacto standard for 3rd-party app notifications on OS X.